# Python requests.get() is returning empty result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am writing a script which will poll Jenkins plugin API to fetch a list of plugin dependencies. For this I have used `requests` module of python. It keeps returning empty response, whereas I am getting a JSON response in Postman.

```
import requests

def get_deps():
    url = "https://plugins.jenkins.io/api/plugin/CFLint"
    headers = {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
    }
    reqs = requests.get(url, headers)
    return reqs.status_code
    return reqs.json()

get_deps()
```

[image: Postman_Result]

The output is as follows.

```
C:\Users\krisT\eclipse-workspace\jenkins>python jenkins.py

C:\Users\krisT\eclipse-workspace\jenkins>
```

Where am I making a mistake? Everything looks correct to me.

---

**Instead of return I had to save the response to a variable and print the response. My question felt like a noob.**

```
s = requests.Session()
def get_deps():
    url = "https://plugins.jenkins.io/api/plugin/CFLint"
    reqs = s.get(url)
    res = reqs.json()
    print(res)

get_deps()
```

Comment: There is no `print` in a program

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
def test_requests():
    response = s.get(_URL)
    response.status_code
    return response.text
```

Comment: The output is still empty.

Comment: change return response.text to print response.text

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added the snippet modification which had worked below the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to either print or save the return given from `reqs.json()`.
Also please remove the additional `return reqs.status_code`

Comment: Can you please share an example?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added the snippet modification which had worked below the question. Thank you :)